# c++ Creating a new thread from a member function and moving the object and the entire

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, memory

according to the code bellow, is myClass1 object and myClass2 obj (which is the myClass1 object's member )  moving to the new thread with their memory(Like std::move()) ?

```
class myClass1{

  public:
   myClass2 obj;

    myClass1(myClass2 * obj) {
        this.obj = *obj;

    }
    thread spawn() {
        return std::thread([this] { this->Run(); });
    }
    void Run() {
        cout << "new thread" << endl;
    }
}
myClass2{
   public :
    string str;
  MyClass2(string str){
    this.str = str;
}

}
int main(){
  myClass1 object(new myClass2("test"));
  thread t = object.spawn();
 t.join();
 ........
}
```

Comment: Does this even compile?

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: its just to show the concept but if you want to compile it ,it should have a join for the new thread and a definition for myclass2 :)

Comment: *"It should have..."* you should provide it

Comment: You still don't have a compilable example. In your constructor, `this.obj = obj;` is a type error. Do you want a *value* of type `myClass2` or a(n owning) raw pointer to `myClass2`?

Comment: the obj is pointer because i dynamically create it by passing the new myClass2  . I dont want to point to a variable in the main thread i want to move it to the new thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, your `main` will call `std::terminate`, because you discard a joinable `std::thread`.

If you join it, `main` will block until the thread has finished. `object` will remain alive for the entire duration of `Run`.

If you detach it, `main` *may* end before the thread does, `object` will cease to exist and the `this` in `myClass1::Run` will be invalid. Undefined Behaviour.

A tidy up of your code

```
class myClass1 {
    myClass2 obj;

public:
    // Take by rvalue, uses the move constructor for obj
    myClass1(myClass2 && obj) : obj(obj) {}

    std::thread spawn() {
        return std::thread([this] 
        {
            // This is suspicious, but safe
            auto self = std::move(*this); 
            self.Run(); 
        });
    }

    void Run() {
        std::cout << "new thread" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    // new is not required
    myClass1 object(myClass2("test"));
    object.spawn().join();
    /* other stuff, not involving object */
    return 0;
}
```

Even more of a tidy up

```
class myClass1 {
    myClass2 obj;

public:
    // Take by rvalue, uses the move constructor for obj
    myClass1(myClass2 && obj) : obj(obj) {}

    void Run() {
        std::cout << "new thread" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    // Just create the instance of myClass1 as a parameter to `std::thread`'s constructor
    std::thread(&myClass1::Run, myClass1(myClass2("test"))).join();
    /* other stuff */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Dear Caleth im aware of your point, as i mentioned in the comment of my question  , in the end of main i add .... which contains the join.my question was about moving the object into its own member func by moving its memory too

Comment: @AmirRasti You don't move any objects. You create **a copy** of the `this` pointer, which becomes the `this` pointer within `Run`

Comment: You'd have to `std::move(*this)` into a local in the lambda, then call Run on that local

Comment: Then please  post it as an answer an ill tik it.

Comment: @AmirRasti I have an alternative that side-steps the need to `std::move(*this)`

Comment: You don't need to `std::move(myClass1(myClass2("test")))`, it is already a prvalue

Answer (score 1):

No; creating a thread does not magically make the thread take ownership of that memory.  If you create an object on the stack, create a thread that uses it; and then unwind the stack, destroying the object; with the thread still running, you will have undefined behaviour.

If you want to give ownership of some data to the thread, the easiest way to do it is with a shared pointer.

Comment: thanks, in my case i want give the ownership of my obj and all its fields to the new thread so that if the thread finishes all the memory is released.if you modify this code to achive this i ll tik your answer .thanks